# Howto install Windows Embedded Standard (Compact) or at least get .iso

Tags: windows-embedded-7

I tried to get "Evaluation copy" from Microsoft.com officially.

They don't give *.iso file to download. Instead, they provide about 7Gb of some data...

I don't know what to do with them. I just want to play with Windows Embedded on my Thin Client.

Can you give me some useful links on how to either generate iso files or may be direct links to *.iso files.

The Thin Client has Compact Flash x300 2Gb and came without any OS preinstalled (my choice). Now I want to play with various systems including THinstation...after some test with Thinstation I wanted to turn to Windows Embedded. The model 100% supports Windows Embedded

Answer (score 1):

You won't get an iso download file, Windows embedded (download) comes as an exe which you install on the server for your thin client.

You will find instructions on this page below the download link [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19004)

Comment: You mean that the "server" becomes the boot server for the thin clients? But how about the preloaded Thin Clients? I mean that some TC's are coming with Windows Embedded installed on them?

Comment: Post back with the make/model of your TC, there are diskless, SSD, mini IDE, etc versions. Some with the OS preinstalled, some that network boot.

Comment: It has Compact Flash x300 2Gb. And it comes without any OS preinstalled (my choice). Now I want to play with various systems including THinstation...after some test with Thinstation I wanted to turn to Windows Embedded. The model 100% supports Windows Embedded it's just me who bought it without any OS. I had an option to get with windows Embedded preinstalled.

Comment: I've added that to your post. My knowledge is limited to diskless TCs so, rather than offer guesses, I'll leave this to someone else, good luck

Comment: thanks but can we say it's a "diskless" if it has 2Gb of Compact Flash memory?

Comment: TCs use flash memory for storing the OS locally so it fulfills the role of a disk